# tclsh is stuck when executing external commands

Tags: tcl, tclsh

When I type

> exec vim

in tclsh it causes a jam, is there a way to catch this wrong usage behavior?

If I accidentally trigger such stuck tclsh behavior, how should I go back to tclsh?

```
tclsh8.5 % exec vim
```

At this time ctrl+c do not work.
I don't want to use ctrl+z.

Comment: `:q` will exit vim (And then you'll see a warning about how the output isn't a terminal).

Answer (score 0):

The `exec` command in Tcl launches the other program as a subprocess and waits for it to terminate so that it can detect whether that command failed and report whatever output it produces as the command result. (That wait only blocks the current thread.) This is really good for some commands, but bad for others; vim is one of the not-very-good ones, especially as it doesn't really produce any output that `exec` can use as its result. On the other hand, provided you exit it then it will at least work. (You might also need to give `<@stdin >@stdout` arguments to `exec` to pass through standard input and output, things that an interactive editor might care about.)

Technically, you could launch vim as a background subprocess with `exec vim &` and the Tcl script would not wait (the result of the `exec` would be the process ID in that case).

Comment: Exiting `vim` itself is another topic. Tcl provides no special help for it.

Comment: Is it possible to start a separate terminal while executing these external commands?

Comment: Many terminal programs let you do that; you'll need to check their documentation.  If you're doing that, you probably want to launch them as background tasks as terminal programs may well exit in unexpected ways.